# Generic list of Exception

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I want to create a list of exception which can hold different type of exception. I tried below code but it is not working. Is there a way to create such list ?

```
List<? extends Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        exceptions.add(RuntimeException.class);
```

Comment: This is an unusual thing to ask for.  I sense an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to write a retry functionality and want to check if exception raised is one of the exception from list. If yes then retry else don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hold **list of exception classes**, then you have defined the list incorrectly.

It should be

```
List<Class<? extends Exception>> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want to hold **list of exception instances**, then Generic Wildcards wont work. This is a drawback of using wildcards in Generics. You can read more about the limitations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783049/java-generics-wildcards-and-their-limitations).

You can simply use as @slartidan mentioned:

```
    List<Exception> myExceptionHolder = new ArrayList<>();
    myExceptionHolder.add(new RuntimeException());
    myExceptionHolder.add(new ArithmeticException());

    Assert.assertTrue(myExceptionHolder.get(0) instanceof RuntimeException );
    Assert.assertTrue(myExceptionHolder.get(1) instanceof ArithmeticException );
```

Or you can have a class like this (if you have some other complex use case):

```
public class MyExceptionHolder<T extends Exception> {
  private List<T> exceptions;

  public MyExceptionHolder() {
    this.exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public List<T> getExceptions() {
    return new ArrayList<>(exceptions); //get a clone
  }

  public void addExceptions(T exception) {
    this.exceptions.add(exception);
  }
}
```

and to use it:

```
    MyExceptionHolder myExceptionHolder = new MyExceptionHolder();
    myExceptionHolder.addExceptions(new RuntimeException());
    myExceptionHolder.addExceptions(new ArithmeticException());

    List exs = myExceptionHolder.getExceptions();
    Assert.assertTrue(exs.get(0) instanceof RuntimeException );
    Assert.assertTrue(exs.get(1) instanceof ArithmeticException );
```

Comment: But `MyExceptionHolder myExceptionHolder = new MyExceptionHolder();` could be simplified to `List<Exception> myExceptionHolder = new ArrayList<>();` - without any wildcards. And the code would run fine.

Comment: True. It will definitely serve the purpose of holding all types of Exceptions and in much simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a list that holds different classes that all extends Exception, then you probably you mean this:

```
  List<Class<? extends Exception>> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
    exceptions.add(RuntimeException.class);
```